# `marshal data too short` error message while installing watir-webdriver on Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, installation, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a clean installation of Windows XP (Professional, Version 2002, Service Pack 3) in VMware Fusion virtual machine (3.1.2 332101). (Host machine is MacBook Pro, Mac OS 10.6.7.) XP installation has 512 MB RAM and is fully updated, except I left Internet Explorer at version 6.

I have installed Ruby and RubyGems:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\zeljko>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.6.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby187/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - C:/Documents and Settings/zeljko/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

When I try to install watir-webdriver gem, I get this error message:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\zeljko>gem install watir-webdriver
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    marshal data too short
```

I am searching around, but did not find the solution yet.

Comment: That things are on a VM should not matter at least to Watir. (but thanks for including that info)  I run a ton of watir stuff on Hyper-V and Virtual-Box VM's and it works just fine.   OTOH I have not taken the plunge into using web-driver, so potentially it could be an issue.

Comment: And for god sakes man, how can you refer to any system still running IE6 as 'fully patched'.   And more seriously, given MS themselves is trying to kill it off (see http://ie6countdown.com/ ) why use it for testing?  Usage in most of the world outside of SE Asia is generally under 5% with a few countries (Go Finland! Go Norway!) under 1%.   It's time to tighten up the test matrix and scrub support for IE6  (even MS wants you to do it!)

Comment: I have Vista and 7 VMs with IE 7, 8 and 9, so I have decided to leave XP VM on IE 6, just for fun. :)

Comment: Fun??   Zeljko I never knew you were a Masochist!   LOL

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[jarib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199912/jarib) suggested I should delete `.gem` folder (`C:\Documents and Settings\zeljko\.gem`) and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### If the problem remains

Reinstall all the gems:

```
sudo gem list | cut -d" " -f1 > gem_list.txt

cat gem_list.txt | xargs sudo gem uninstall -aIx

cat gem_list.txt | xargs sudo gem instal
```

Answer (score -2):

Delete .gem folder in directory which is hidden..

Comment: How is this different to my answer?

Comment: @ŽeljkoFilipin i thought we may won get such problem in ubuntu.. but yesterday i faced it... so i just forgot to mention ubuntu in my answer :)