# Cannot install Ruby Gems in Windows 7

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, compass-sass

I have successfully installed Ruby Gems on my Mac many times.  I need to configure a Windows 7 Enterprise virtual machine with Compass, Sass and Suzy.

I downloaded an installed Ruby on the Windows machine with the installer, 1.9.3.  I ran `gem update --system` which updated Rubygems to 1.8.4.

I was able to install Sass 3.2 by running `gem install sass`

However, if I run `gem install compass` or `gem install susy` I get an error:

```
Error while excecuting gem .. (ArgumentError) marshall data too short
```

Any ideas?  At this point, I can't install those gems.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409675/marshal-data-too-short-error-message-while-installing-watir-webdriver-on-windo

Comment: My only guess would be that the installer installed in in c:/Program Files and the gem isn't liking the space in the path.

Comment: @SumitJain That one doesn't help me as the path is no longer valid for Windows 7. And I can't locate a .gem folder anywhere.

Comment: @Steve take a look to the output of `gem env` command under GEM PATHS, the second one (since the first is your Ruby installation). Browse to that folder and will find `.gem` folder. On Windows 7 it will be `C:\Users\yourusername\.gems`

Comment: @LuisLavena It has the path as N:/.gem/ruby/1.9.1 and C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1

I removed .gem and still same error installing Compass

Comment: OK, I hate DOS (used to Unix).  I finally cleared it all out with `rmdir /S .gem` and then was able to install Compass and Susy.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative solution..: **Download gem compass** from [here](http://rubygems.org/) to your ruby root folder. Then try again
`gem install compass`
It should install this time..Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue, updating rubygems system solved it. Just use the following command

```
gem update --system
```

Answer (score 0):

For those finding this question, many great tips here.  Using them, I found this solution to work:

At the N: prompt in "start command line with ruby environment", I used the command `rmdir /S .gem` which deleted all gems.  I then installed them again with `gem install` as directed on their respective host web pages.  Hope this helps someone.